# Override the JSON stringify method in process.send()

Tags: node.js, json, ipc, node-ipc

I am calling `process.send(val)` with an IPC message between parent and child. The object val has some arbitrary circular references, that are hard to prune, reliably. I have a custom JSON stringify function that can handle circular refs. Is there a way to override the `JSON.stringify` method within `process.send()`?

Something like:

```
const serializableObj = {
  [process.send.stringify](){
      return myCustomStringify(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: Stringify it before sending

Comment: If it's your code on both ends, then just send your custom JSON string that you can decode properly on the other end.  Or, create a duplicate object that has only what you're trying to send in it (and no circular references) and send that safe duplicate.